# Curating terrible duplicate questions

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

Whenever a new question comes up that I'm certain has been asked before but I don't already know the appropriate canonical for, I'll start googling to see if I can find a good target to close it with.  I'll gather up a bunch of results and close them all as duplicates of the best one.

Yesterday, I was searching for a specific error that can only have one explanation.  What I found in the top 10 search results limited to SO were questions like this:

- [No MCVE w/ VLQ answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30279384/suzy-2-2-5-base-level-rules-cannot-contain-the-parent-selector-referencing-cha)
- [Not reproducible (possibly due to a buggy unofficial compiler)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22072465/trying-to-convert-less-to-scss-hit-a-snag)
- [No MCVE w/ answers that are VLQ and NAA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12989500/how-to-handle-full-width-element-outside-of-a-960-compass-susy-grid)

Those are easily cleaned up, but my primary concern is for questions like this one that has absolutely nothing to do with this error message: [sass if even number in for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27648567/sass-if-even-number-in-for-loop).

This question is a duplicate of one of these two questions:

- [Math with interpolated variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8254941/math-with-interpolated-variables)
- [If statement using interpolation always evaluates to true in Sass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34770040/if-statement-using-interpolation-always-evaluates-to-true-in-sass)

However, I can't tell what "doesn't work" here means because the OP never clarified.  The OP made absolutely no effort to examine what went wrong and chose a question title that reflected the task being performed, rather than the problem.  It needs a new title to be useful, but I can only think of so many ways to phrase any given problem *that hasn't already been used before*.

Worse, the answerer makes assumptions about what "doesn't work" means and makes references to a specific error message that is (probably) unrelated to the actual problem.  If I remove this information so that it stops showing up in search results, the answer becomes code only.

Is there such a thing as a duplicate that is unsalvageable?  Should we be cleaning these up?  Or should we always be trying to make an effort to turn these into useful signposts?

Comment: "Is there such a thing as a duplicate that is unsalvageable?" It depends on what sort of unsalvageable. If it's unclear what is being asked or if the problem cannot be determined due to missing critical information, then what the question is a duplicate of, or whether it is a duplicate, becomes unclear in turn.

Comment: Sometimes a poor duplicate clearly indicates what's wrong (eg. the provided code only produces one error), but the title is terrible (no one else will find this question useful based on the title).  I *could* fix the title, but eventually I'll run out of unique, descriptive titles to use.

Comment: @BoltClock that, or incorrectly closed as duplicated.